# exchange data between activities

Tags: android

I created 2 `Activities`, Main and Second. And I want to send text, put in the box `EditText` from Main to Second activity. Id of first `EditText` is `UserName`, and of the second is `Description`.

The code of the Main activity is:

```
package com.example.test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);           
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", UserName.getText().toString()); 
        intent.putExtra("gift", Description.getText().toString());  
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void ButtonOneClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Full code of the Second Activity is:
    package com.example.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextOne);

        String user = "ЖЫвотное";
        String gift = "дырку от бублика";

        user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        gift = getIntent().getExtras().getString("gift");

        txtInfo.setText(user + " , вам передали " + gift);
    }
}
```

and errors:

```
main.java: Description cannot be resolved
main.java: UserName cannot be resolved
```

sorry for my english

Thanks for help

P.S. I'm studying java and programming for android just third day, please don't throw stones to me.

Comment: Try to cast the Username and gift edittext to your own local variables of edit text using the id of the username and gift. And then use get text on the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You'd then refer to your `R` class file, that is:

```
EditText desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Description);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included

```
EditText UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
EditText Description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
```

in your onCreate() method in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

As you reference `UserName` and `Description` here refer to them as they are classes. Unless you have such classes an error will be stated because these classes can not be found (or "resolved").
You can even notice this by the syntax highlight. Do you see the words a displayed in a lght green/turquoise like `Main` or `Intent`?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", UserName.getText().toString()); 
    intent.putExtra("gift", Description.getText().toString());  
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Instead you want instances of the class `EditText` which you call `userName` and `description`. On these objects you can perform `getText()` and work your way along. :)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    intent.putExtra("username", userName.getText().toString()); 
    intent.putExtra("gift", description.getText().toString());  
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Please notice I've changed the names of your variables to lowerCase starting [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Though not an explicit rule it's considered good practise to start variable names with lower case letters ('userName`,`description`,`intent`) while **C**lass references like (`ÈditText`,`Main`,`Second`) are started with upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialize the username & description in your java;

```
EditText us_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
EditText us_desp=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.desp);
```